# Individual Pending Intent for each button on widget

Tags: android, android-intent, widget, android-widget

first of all sorry for my bad english

I have a AppWidget that use a Intent Service for doing its job 
my app widget has 3 buttons , and if user press each button go to main activity , but with different ContentViews , 
Now the problem is any Time user click on any button , it goes to main activity but with first contentview , and my ID always is 1 ; 
this is my code;
**intent service**

```
public static class ToggleService extends IntentService{
    public ToggleService(){
        super("AppWidget$ToggleService");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ComponentName me = new ComponentName(this, AppWidget.class);
        AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        mgr.updateAppWidget(me, buildUpdate(this));




    }
    public RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context ctx){
        RemoteViews rmt = new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        Intent i3 = new Intent(this,AppWidget.class);
        i3.putExtra("ID", 3);
        PendingIntent pi3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, i3, 0);
        Intent i1 = new Intent(this, AppWidget.class);
        i1.putExtra("ID", 1);
        PendingIntent pi1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, i1, 0);
        Intent i2 = new Intent(this,AppWidget.class);
        i2.putExtra("ID", 2);
        PendingIntent pi2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, i2, 0);




        rmt.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetButton1, pi1);
        rmt.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetButton2, pi2);
        rmt.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetButton3, pi3);



        return rmt;

    }
}
```

OnRecive

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(intent.getAction()==null){
        int ID_CODE=intent.getIntExtra("ID", 0);
        Intent i = new Intent(context , MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("ID", ID_CODE);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);



    }else{
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

OnUpdate

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    context.startService(new Intent(context,ToggleService.class));
}
```

MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11){
        getActionBar().hide();

    }
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    if(i.getAction()!=null){        

    setContentView(R.layout.launcher);

    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }, 2000);}
    else {
        int ID=i.getIntExtra("ID", 0);
        if(ID==1){
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(ID), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(ID==2){

            setContentView(R.layout.bank_main);
            Toast.makeText(this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(ID==3){
            setContentView(R.layout.other_main);
            Toast.makeText(this, "3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    }
```

The Problem is each time i click on each widgetButton , Value of ID is always 1 ,and it never change to 2 , or 3 
**please help me**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your `PendingIntent`s, you are reusing the same one over and over again. You want to have 3 `PendingIntent`s active simultaneously. To do that you need to make sure that the parameters to the call to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` ensure that you will get a unique `PendingIntent`. The easiest way to do that is to use different unique `requestCode` parameters. Like this:

```
    Intent i3 = new Intent(this,AppWidget.class);
    i3.putExtra("ID", 3);
    PendingIntent pi3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 3, i3, 0);
    Intent i1 = new Intent(this, AppWidget.class);
    i1.putExtra("ID", 1);
    PendingIntent pi1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 1, i1, 0);
    Intent i2 = new Intent(this,AppWidget.class);
    i2.putExtra("ID", 2);
    PendingIntent pi2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 2, i2, 0);
```

NOTE: Just having different "extras" doesn't make the `Intent` parameter to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` unique. You'll need to use either different `Intent` ACTIONs or different `requestCode` parameters.